# How do I change my URL to a clean URL with directories?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I would like my site (like most sites) to have clean URLs, so that every page is in a directory format.

Presently, I developed my site so that if I go to site.com/mypage, it treats it like site.com/?p=mypage. I do this through .htaccess using the following script:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+/mysite/index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mysite/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?page=%1 [L,QSA]
```

This works great. Now I want to use a directory style format, such that I can do site.com/mypage/myinfo. I tried doing this a couple different ways.

First, I just tried supplying the directory in the "p" variable, such that if I supplied site.com/?p=mypage%2Fmyinfo, the result would be site.com/mypage/myinfo. This works, but it tries to find a page in a directory which doesn't exist. So my site breaks.

Second, I figured I could put them both as separate variables, such as site.com/?p=mypage&c=myinfo. This may work, but I am struggling to rewrite the .htaccess so that it takes both bariables and places them correctly.

I would welcome any assistance in either helping me rewrite this .htaccess file to accommodate both, or recommendations for another approach for doing what I need.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please do let me know if my answer has helped you here, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
##New rule for uri mypage/myinfo to be served by index.php internally.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(mypage)/(myinfo)/?$ index.php?p=$1&c=$2 [NC,L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+/mysite/index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mysite/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?page=%1 [L,QSA]
```